# Random graphical glitches in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

I was restarting my laptop because of some problems opening files and applications and it hung for about 10 minutes on the shutting down screen so I had no choice but to manually kill the power. When I turned it back on, I started noticing minor graphical glitches like:

[image]

The bench should not have that black graphical glitch.

I also noticed that the text in some applications is now much blockier (TeXstudio)

[image]

I also notice some more subtle jaggedness in icons and in general a washed out feel to the display.

I tried both rolling back and updating the graphics driver (Intel HD Graphics 5500, Lenovo T450 less than a year old), but no luck. I have also tried restarting, etc.

I am running Windows 7.

Any possible explanations for this? Would I be correct in saying it's a software problem? When I hover over the glitch above with the mouse pointer, for example, it still remains.

Comment: I turned on and off clear text, but with no luck. However, I then changed the colour to 32 bit and the text anti-aliasing problem in TeXStudio somehow resolved. However, there are still graphical glitches. I presume it's software related.

Answer (score 2):

**Occasionally I've had seen issues with Windows Updates**

Sometimes when updates run they will update a driver or a .dll we don't want updated.  Due to some misalignment with an update or bugfix some of the issues you are experiencing will arise.

Typically I will [show hidden hardware using this procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff184583.aspx).

Afterword, I will delete all video related devices and allow the generic driver to operate the display.  Then, run windows update and ensure you have all of your service packs/drivers up to date from Microsoft.

After that is complete, get the factory driver and install it for your GPU.  This will hopefully give you a nice clean and uncontaminated driver install.